# Javascript Array and Object keys

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON response I'm getting back from a custom web service that looks like the following:

```
var data = { 
    AZ:{charge:123,count:324},
    TN:{charge:123,count:7545},
    TX:{charge:165,count:345}
}
```

And I wish to loop through using an array of state abbreviations that I get back via another json call. I don't need to loop through all the states just specific ones that are dictated by this json call. So I end up with an array of state abbreviations that looks like so:

```
var states = ["AZ","TX"];
```

Then I attempt to loop through the data and pull out the charge property like so:

```
console.log(data[states[i]].charge);
```

However when I do this I get back an undefined from data. When I get out the state abbreviation it's there and when I log out the data right before this call all the data is there. I can reference each record in data by doing the following though

```
console.log(data["TN"].charge);
```

Anyone care to explain why `console.log(data[states[i]].charge);` but the other does? Also what can I do to rectify this problem?

Comment: Obviously because there is no property with name `states[i]` in `data` object. Please post the code which works with these variables.

Comment: Sorry typo, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `AX` and `TX` as keys for `data` but they are not strings, they are variables. Add quotes to make them strings.

```
var states = ['AX','TX'];
```

And to avoid a possible error in your code, check if `data[states[i]]` is not `undefined` before trying to access the `charge` property.

```
var stateData = data[states[i]];

if(!stateData) return; //or `continue` if inside a loop to skip

console.log(stateData.charge);
```

Comment: Then it will be an exception of undefined `AX`.

Answer (score 0):

If `i = 0` then you should get undefined because `states[0] === "AX"` and there is no `"AX"` key in your `data`. If `i = 1` you should get `165`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a typo but it looks like your list of status in var states is not the same has the keys in your data object, specifically "AX" is not a key in your data object example

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this:

```
<script lang='javascript'>  
var data = { 
    AZ:{charge:123,count:324},
    TN:{charge:123,count:7545},
    TX:{charge:165,count:345}
}

var states = ['AX','TX'];
console.log(data[states[1]].charge);
console.log(data["TN"].charge);

</script>
```

And it output:

```
165
123
```

So if its a call coming back from an api call its probably coming back as a variable so you'll have to reference it first and then pass it to the console. Something like:

```
var charge = data[states[i]].charge
console.log(charge)
```

You should also check if the states[i] exists in the data array first as well.